# PHP struggling to decode JSON

Tags: php, laravel, json

I have script that calls at script via cURL. It looks like this,

```
Route::get('login-redirect', function() {

if (Input::has('error')) {

    return Input::get('error_description');
}
if (Input::has('code')) {

   $fields = array(
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' => 'admin@local.com',
        'password' => 'passwohrd',
        'client_id' => 'testclient'
   );

   $fieldstring = http_build_query($fields, "\n");

   $url = "http://apitest.local/api/v1/get-token";

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldstring);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   $json = json_decode($result);

   curl_close($ch);

   $fields = array('access_token' => '3c1e6b099f172fc01304403939edf8e56904ab61');
   $fieldstring = http_build_query($fields, "\n");

   $url = "http://apitest.local/api/v1/me";

   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldstring);

   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

   dd($result);

}
```

The json returned looks like this, if I do `dd($json)`

`{"content":null,"error":true,"error_description":"Invalid username and password combination"}int(1)`

I feel like after running it through `json_decode` I should be able to just output `$json->error` but no.

The JSON gets made in the following class, but I cannot see anything odd here either, I am doing incorrect, or do I misunderstand json_decode?

```
<?php
namespace Shaunpersad\ApiFoundation\Http;

use App;
use Response;

class ErrorResponse
{
    public static function make($message = '', $status = 200, array $headers = array(), $options = 0)
    {
        $response = App::make(
            'api_response_array',
            array(
                'content' => null,
                'error' => true,
                'error_description' => $message
            )
        );

        return Response::json($response, $status, $headers, $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `int(1)` is actually contained in your response and not a copy/paste error the response is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not have CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - your curl_exec returns output buffer directly to the screen.

Second of all, it looks like you have var_dump somewhere and I cannot see where :)

Third of all - you didn't asked any direct question.

**Edit**

Okay i've read it few time and answer below. The dd() function is truly a var_dump wrapper but it is dumping var_dump data into json format afaics.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As stated in the other answers, you're not actually receiving the output because you haven't set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`. So `curl_exec()` will echo out the response to the DOM and return true (**`1`**) as your `curl` request ran successfully.

You'll be able to run the below stuff by setting this in your curl request somewhere:

```
curl_setop(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

---

`dd()` is a [`laravel function`](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#miscellaneous) and this is what the documentation says:

> Dump the given variable and end execution of the script.

I'd presume it is just a wrapper function for a prettier looking `var_dump()` (<sup>*As I don't use laravel, I wouldn't know its exact output.*</sup>).

What you want is to decode the `$result` that is returned from your `cUrl`. Something like this should suffice:

```
$data = json_decode($result);

echo $data->error_description;
```

The successfully decoded object looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [content] => 
    [error] => 1
    [error_description] => Invalid username and password combination
)
```

[<kbd>**Example**</kbd>](https://eval.in/172588)

---

You can even test your boolean `error` value like this now:

```
if($data->error) {
    //....true
} else {
    //....false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got as an output is not from `dd($json)`:

```
// this part has been output by curl_exec():
{"content":null,"error":true,"error_description":"Invalid username and password combination"}
// only this part comes from dd($json):
int(1)
```

Here's why:

```
// no CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, so curl_exec() outputs result and returns true:
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// thus $result = true;

// so here $json = 1, since this is what json_decode(true) will return
$json = json_decode($result);

// then you did dd($json), so it just appended var_dump(1) to the output:
{"content":null,"error":true,"error_description":"Invalid username and password combination"}int(1)
```